# How do I transform, with long division, this polynomial into the answer given?

Tags: polynomials

I need to transform:

$ \frac {x^5}{(x-2)(x+2)(x^2+4)}  $

into

$ \frac{-2x}{x^2+4} + x + \frac{1}{x-2} + \frac{1}{x+2} $

How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try. We have $$\frac{x^5}{(x-2)(x+2)(x^2+4)} = \frac{x^5}{x^4-16}= x + \frac{16x}{x^4-16} = x + 2x\left(\frac{1}{x^2-4} - \frac{1}{x^2+4}\right) = x -\frac{2x}{x^2+4} +\frac{2x}{(x+2)(x-2)} = x -\frac{2x}{x^2+4} + \frac{1}{x-2} + \frac{1}{x+2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

First, you should notice the difference of squares formula (twice) in the denominator.  $(x-2)(x+2)=x^2-4$  Then $(x^2-4)(x^2+4)=x^4-16$ so we have $\frac {x^5}{x^4-16}=x+\frac {16x}{x^4-16}$  The rest is a [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) of the second term.